# HTTP Status 500 - file:/survey.jsp(16,15) jsp:getProperty for bean with name 'survey'. Name was not previously introduced as per JSP.5.3

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

Hi I am new to JSP and JavaBean. I am practicing by writing an application where multiple pages will share a javabean component. The page "check.jsp" instantiates the bean and sets a property without any error. But whenever I try to getProperty in another jsp, `survey.jsp`, I get the **error**:

> HTTP Status 500 - file:/survey.jsp(16,15) jsp:getProperty for bean with name 'survey'. Name was not previously introduced as per JSP.5.3

I have double checked that the name in the get and set properties are exactly the same as my bean id in the  action element. Please I need help

**CHECK.jsp**:

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <jsp:useBean id="survey" scope="application" class="appScope.SurveyBean"/>
        <jsp:setProperty name="survey" property="quantity" value='<%= request.getParameter("title")%>' />

        <form action="/appScope/survey.jsp" method="POST">
            <h3> Thanks for your input</h3>
            <h3> Please check the survey summary status if you want</h3><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Check Status" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my javabean: **SurveyBean.java**:

```
 package appScope;

    public class SurveyBean {
    private int javaQuantity = 0;
    private int csQuantity = 0;

    public int getJavaQuantity()
    {
        return javaQuantity;
    }

    public int getCsQuantity()
    {
        return csQuantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(String bookTitle)
    {
        try
        {
            if(bookTitle.equals("java"))
            {
                javaQuantity++;
            }
            if (bookTitle.equals("c"))
            {
                csQuantity++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is **survey.jsp** where i get the error:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Survey Summary</h1>
           //ERROR IS HERE
        Java = <jsp:getProperty name="survey" property="javaQuantity" /> <br/> 
        C# = <jsp:getProperty name="survey" property="csQuantity" /> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Name was not previously introduced

This indicates that you haven't told your JSP about this bean as of yet. You are directly using the `<jsp:getProperty>` before letting the JSP know about the bean.

You need to use the `<jsp:useBean>` tag to define the bean in the *survey.jsp*.The `name` attribute of the `getProperty` tag must match the `id` attribute of the `useBean` tag :

```
<jsp:useBean id="survey" class="appScope.SurveyBean" scope="request">
```

But this won't work , unless you set the bean named `survey` in the request scope in the *check.jsp* file and post that request to the *survey.jsp*.

Comment: Thanks this works. So in every jsp page that needs to access the common bean, i have to define that bean using <jsp:useBean> in that page?